# How does vim support C/S mode?

Tags: vim

I have investigated that vim can be used as client/server mode software with the feature: +clientserver. But it is not what I imagine.

I wonder if there's a way to use vim like google wave/google doc. In that mode, I can edit one file on two connected computers simultaneously.

+clientserver can do this: a 'vim server' and many 'vim client' connected to it and send edit command to it. but I can only use 'vim --remote-send' to do that, it's not WYSIWG and not convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Vim is probably not what you think it is: it is completely the opposite of WYSIWYG.

You can connect to another computer via SSH, launch Vim on that computer and edit away through your terminal. I and a lot of people do that every day: it works *amazingly* well.

You can also use Vim on machine A and edit a file on machine B via SCP.

You can also go down the tmux rabbit hole and use its session sharing capabilities. Doing pair programming that way is quite trendy ATM.

Also your questions are probably too broad for this site, consider SU, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `tmux`. It supports multiple clients connecting to the same session.

Answer (score 0):

Collaborative editing once made it to #9 on the [Vim wishlist](http://www.vim.org/sponsor/vote_results.php), but it is unlikely to come soon, as nobody seems to be working on it. If you'd like to contribute that feature, you're welcome! (But it won't be quick and easy to implement!)

> add collaborative editing: changes made to a buffer show up in another Vim in a second